# Does Cloudfoundry router provide HTTPS support?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am aware that there are two versions of CF routers:

1. GoRouter: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/gorouter
2. Older version: https://github.com/cloudfoundry-attic/router

My question is: which one supports HTTPS incoming requests, if any.

If they do support HTTPS, do they terminate SSL session and forwards the request in plain HTTP to the application?

Comment: can you explain why you wish to do HTTPS termination with CF Router? There is the HAProxy component for that. The request is unencrypted when he reaches routers. HAProxy does the termination. You can replace HAProxy with an external load balancer (for example F5)

Comment: Thanks, I know about HAProxy and NGINX can do the SSL termination. But can the router do that? Someone who is familiar with the code (of both routers) can answer it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GoRouter does not provide SSL termination.  I would suggest using Nginx or HAProxy.